# How do you change the percentages and column numbers of a fluid layout in Dreamweaver cs6?

Tags: dreamweaver, fluid-layout

I am using Dreamweaver cs6 to create a fluid layout.  When the new document option window first opens it gives you options on the percentages and number of columns for each device.  I have done this, but would like to change the percentages and number of columns after the document has been created.  Is there a way to change the percentages and column numbers of a fluid layout in Dreamweaver cs6 after the document has been created?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit these values in the css file DW asked you to create:

```
/*
Dreamweaver Fluid Grid Properties
----------------------------------
dw-num-cols-mobile:     5;
dw-num-cols-tablet:     8;
dw-num-cols-desktop:    10;
dw-gutter-percentage:   25;

Inspiration from "Responsive Web Design" by Ethan Marcotte 
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design

and Golden Grid System by Joni Korpi
http://goldengridsystem.com/
*/
```

After saving, exiting and re-opening your project the columns and gutter percentage will haven been updated.

Answer (score 0):

*Dreamweaver CS6: The Missing Manual* (https://www.inkling.com/read/dreamweaver-cs6-missing-manual-david-sawyer-mcfarland-1st/chapter-11/fluid-grid-layouts) says:

> Unfortunately, once you pick a gutter value, there’s no way to return to this [the "New Fluid Grid Layout"] screen and change it. In fact, since Dreamweaver uses this value to make some complex calculations concerning the columns you insert, there’s no easy way to change this value once you create the layout.

We could perhaps try changing the width and padding numbers in the existing FGL CSS (those numbers Dreamweaver calculated to the fourth decimal upon the file's creation), but it's probably easier just to create a new fluid grid layout style sheet. A more user-friendly solution would be welcome, however.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i found a simple solution. You create a new fluid grid layout with the changes you wont to make you save it so that it will creat for you the new css and respond.min.js file. You delete all the other new files you created and you keep only the respond.min.js and you replace the old one with the new one and you finished. Oh keep a copy of the old one just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found a pretty simple solution.
You need to create a new Fluid Grid layout (File - New Fluid Grid Layout), set up the number of columns, widths, and gutters as you want and then save somewhere the new css file. Styles that regulate layout (i.e., widths, margins between columns, and number of columns) are set under .gridContainer so you just need to replace .gridContainer styles in your old fluid layout css file with .gridContainer styles from your new fluid layout css file. Be sure to replace .gridContainer styles for all screen sizes you changed (desktop, table, mobile or all of them).